# Modal from react-native crash or a bug?

Tags: react-native

I simply import Modal from react-native and run simple test.

I found out that if I reload with `<Modal visible={true}>` it just crash my app. It wont reload until I re-open it, it works perfectly fine when reload with `visible={false}`

```
import React , {Component} from 'React';
import {View,Modal,Text} from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Modal visible={true} >
          <Text>Before Reload</Text>
          <Text>when reload only Before reload show up ,no-error or any information</Text>
        </Modal>
      </View>
     )
  }
}
```

!Update. Found out it's a feature. gonna leave it here in case beginner facing the same problem

Comment: It is known where I work that, if you reload your app with a Modal open, you lose control over it because the Modal stays on screen. And since you are setting it's visibility to true, you will always have it open.

Comment: so basically i can call it a feature ?

Comment: thanks for the answer lmao

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want you modal to be opened by default in a class. 
Only make the modal open when you need that i.e on button press etc. If it's open by default try rendering a class instead of a modal

```
import React , {Component} from 'React';
    import {View,Modal,Text} from 'react-native';

    export default class Test extends Component{
      render(){
        return(
          <View>
            <Modal visible={this.state.modalVisibile} > //This is boolean value and update it's value on a button press.
              <Text>Before Reload</Text>
              <Text>when reload only Before reload show up ,no-error or any information</Text>
            </Modal>
          </View>
         )
      }
    }
```

Also, if the modal is opened by default it will cause many issues

Comment: sometimes you just want to make your modal look good, so you need to render it first to save time

Comment: It will look good even then also. There would be a gap of only 1-2 micro seconds only. If you are calling an API inside that modal try calling the api in `didMount()` and save that in state and use that state variable inside your modal. Then show the modal on button click which already has data loaded inside.